# One month from today with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Could you tell me how to get the date where 1 month from today with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

I have tried below one.

```
 myDate = moment().add(1, 'months');
```

resulted format is `Fri Jun 26 2015 00:13:48 GMT+0530`

But I need the format as this `06/26/2015`.So how can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method with `'MM/DD/YYYY'` as parameter

```js
alert(moment().add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Sampath, Format was incorrect updated answer go throgh docs for correct format parameters

Answer (score 2):

Use the moment's format function

```
myDate = moment().add(1, 'months');
console.log(myDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

or

```
myDate = moment().add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

[Check the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for the right format values because 'dd' is "day of the week" not "day". You should use those values in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by using `MM/dd/yyyy` format. I have several guesses

1. If you want to do this `myDate = moment().add('MM/dd/yyyy');` I don't think it is possible. The closest thing you can get is `myDate = moment().add({days: 1, months: 1, years: 1});`. And it is not a big deal to turn `MM/dd/yyyy` to the above object literal format
2. If you want to format the output, use this http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/